# How to modify image caption in posts?

Tags: filters, captions

I am trying to modify the caption of images in posts by filtering `img_caption_shortcode`, and then displaying the content using `the_content()`. I want to add bylines/credit on images, so I have created two fields in ACF that should be added inside the `<figcaption>` on all my posts. Basically I want to do what is description in the [blog](https://allisontarr.com/2018/02/12/acf-custom-field-media-item/).

So from this:

```
<figcaption>
So this is a caption that describes the image.
</figcaption>
```

To this:

```
<figcaption class="post-thumbnail-caption">
So this is a caption that describes the image.
<span class="wp-block-image-byline">Photo: Gregor Gregson</span>
</figcaption>
```

I have tried just doing it as simple as possible, but I can not get it to work. Nothing happans/changes with the following code in my `functions.php` (I did first try the whole code from the example in the blog linked above).

```
add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'my_img_caption_shortcode', 10, 3 );
 
function my_img_caption_shortcode( $output, $attr, $content ) {
    $output = 'test';
    return $output;
 
}
```

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Images can be added in many ways (manually via custom HTML, using the Image block in Gutenberg, added by plugins, etc.), so the hook `img_caption_shortcode` doesn't always get called, hence you'd need to find another way to add the custom field to the caption, e.g. [this for the post thumbnail caption](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_post_thumbnail_caption/).

Comment: @SallyCJ as I myself have found out, yes shortcodes are not called in Gutenberg as it uses Blocks (unless you manually add shortcodes). So one way seems to be filtering `render_block`, and/or editing the standard image block to behave the way I want. So a bit more complicated than the above method.